# navigator.pushReplacementNamed not pushing the next screen in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to implement a conditional login in Flutter, showing different screens after login based on the type of user.

The type of user is determined by a series of methods on my login controller, as follows:

```
Future<ApiResponse> signIn(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email.trim(),
        password: password.trim(),
      );

      //TODO: add to the userType table petOwner users that were registered before this was implemented
      userTypeElement = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('userType')
          .doc(userCredential?.user!.uid)
          .get();

      if (userTypeElement!.exists) {
        userTypeData = userTypeElement?.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
        userType = _stringToEnum(userTypeData!['type']);
        return await _getApiResponse(userType!);
      }

      return ApiPetOwnerResponse(
          model: null, errorMessage: 'Usuario no encontrado.');
    } catch (e) {
      if (e is FirebaseAuthException) {
        return ApiBadResponse(
            model: null,
            errorMessage:
                'El usuario que ingreso no existe, intente de nuevo o registrese');
      } else {
        return ApiBadResponse(model: null, errorMessage: '$e');
      }
    }
  }

  UserType? _stringToEnum(String type) {
    if (type == "owner") return UserType.owner;
    if (type == "veterinarian") return UserType.veterinarian;
    return null;
  }

  Future<ApiResponse> _getApiResponse(UserType type) async {
    if (type == UserType.veterinarian) {
      result = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('veterinarians')
          .doc(userCredential?.user!.uid)
          .get();
      if (result == null) throw Exception('Usuario no encontrado');
      userModel =
          VeterinarianModel.fromJson(result!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>);
      return ApiVeterinarianResponse(
          model: userModel as VeterinarianModel, errorMessage: null);
    }
    if (type == UserType.owner) {
      result = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('owners')
          .doc(userCredential?.user!.uid)
          .get();
      if (result == null) throw Exception('Usuario no encontrado');
      userModel =
          PetOwnerModel.fromJson(result!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>);
      return ApiPetOwnerResponse(
          model: userModel as PetOwnerModel, errorMessage: null);
    }

    return ApiBadResponse(model: null, errorMessage: 'No type found');
  }
```

This logic was implemented because PetOwner and Veterinarian users are stored in different collections in Firestore, so the userType auxiliary collection is consulted to identify the type of user.

This is the logic in my login view, specifically in my Login button:

```
onPressed: loginController.isButtonEnabled
   ? () async {
        final navigator = Navigator.of(context);
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                            );
          final result = await loginController.signIn(
                _emailController.text,
                _passwordController.text);

          if (result.model != null) {
              debugPrint(result.model.toString());
              modelType = result.model.toString();
              switch (modelType) {
                 case "PetOwnerModel":
                 navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
                    homeRoute,
                  );
                  break;
                 case "VeterinarianModel":
                   navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
                     vetHomeRoute,
                   );
                  break;
               }
              } else {
                showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                      title: const Text("Error"),
                      content: Text(result.errorMessage!),
                      actions: <Widget>[
                        TextButton(
                          child: const Text('OK'),
                          onPressed: () {
                            navigator.pop();
                          },
                         )
                       ]),
                    );
                   }
                  }
                 : null,
```

For some reason, the switch statement is not pushing the following Screen based on the result.model value, which I'm converting to string and evaluating as such.

Comment: Does it close the progress dialog. as per my i get, you need to add another pop

Comment: @Md.YeasinSheikh just added the .pop after the progress indicator. The circularProgressIndicator is closed but the app stays on the Login Screen.